# Timed Out, Error when loading Form Design on Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core

I am running Visual Studio on a Windows 11 VM with Parallels on an M1 Mac. Visual studio works perfectly when creating a new project but when I try to open an already created project with a different .Net Framework version than 4.7.2, I cannot open the Designer for the forms in the project.

I tried changing it to 4.7.2 from properties and manually changing in .csproj but this will generate other errors and eventually cause problems to other people opening the project (as it is shared with GIT).
Running the project will not cause problems, the app builds perfectly.

How could I try to solve this problem?

- The full error is: Timed out while connecting to named pipe.

Thank you.

Comment: Related  question - [Timed out while connecting to named pipe when opening windows form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68691756/timed-out-while-connecting-to-named-pipe-when-opening-windows-form-in-net-5-0) - and issue - https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/6420 - suggest this is indeed a dependency problem. What version are you building against?

Comment: Windows .Net 6.0

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/70863542/43846

Comment: I searched for that part of code but I only have a PackageReference inside the ItemGroup Tag.