Visual Studio New Project - Designer Error on startup
I cant seem to find a solution to this - I created a new VB WinForms project and without adding any code, VS throws this error when trying to display the Forms designer. It takes several minutes for the "Loading Designer" message to finally be replaced by this error message and without resolving it I cant really progress.
I've tried the usual re-starts re-boots etc but it repeats every time the New Project is opened.

This is the Call Stack:

Hide Call Stack

at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.Host.ServerProcess.d__36.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.Host.ServerProcess.d__28.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.Host.ServerHostFactory.d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.DesignToolsClientLoader.d__29.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.DesignToolsClientLoader.<>c__DisplayClass25_1.<<-ctor>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Client.DesignToolsClientLoader.d__27.MoveNext()

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/windows-forms-designer-error-Timed-out-w/10620272?q=%5BFixed+in%3A+Visual+Studio+2022+version+17.11%5D&ftype=problem&ref=vs_releasenotes? https://stackoverflow.com/q/68691756/11683?

You need to specify what version of Visual Studio you have, what Template you selected (e.g., Windows Forms App (.NET Framework) / Windows Forms App, other), the selected target .NET version and whether, in Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Preview Features, the Preview Windows Forms out-of-process Designer is selected. If you have the Community Edition, it may not be

Thanks for your reply: I haveMicrosoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.10.0
and the Project Template is a Windows Forms I've several Frameworks but v8.0 is what I started with. The Preview Windows Forms out-of-process IS checked.

You have to be more precise. What did you choose when you selected the Template: Windows Forms App (.NET Framework) or Windows Forms App? The former uses .NET Framework (max. version 4.8.1), the latter .NET (Core) 5+. Quite different things, even though the naming convention is not as descriptive as it could be

It was a Windows Forms App Template - I'm unsure what the difference is?

Open Visual Studio Installer and use it to repair your Visual Studio installation.

The out-of-process Designer is not working at all. There's something wrong with your installation. Check the workloads you have installed, then modify the installation or, as suggested, try to repair it

I faced a similar problem while using VS2019 ,It happened when the project saved to a long path or the path contains many symbols
